# rails : validation vs reject_if in nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms, activemodel

I have a model A which accepts nested attributes for model B. The number of model B entries and whether an entry is required or not is decided based on a 3rd table in db. I use form_for to generate a form with fields_for for model B entries. This is how the validation needs to work:

1. An entry for model B is allowed to be blank if its corresponding `:required` field is false, but it should not be saved, i.e, this entry should not raise validation error but should be rejected by `:reject_if`.
2. An entry whose `:required` field is true is not allowed to be blank. These entries should not be rejected by the `:reject_if` but raise a validation error when it is being saved to db.

   ```
   class modelA < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :modelBs, dependent: :destroy

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :modelBs, reject_if: :not_required_and_blank?

     def not_required_and_blank?
        # return true if modelB.entry is blank && modelB.required_entry? is false
     end
   end

   class modelB < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :modelA
     validates :modelB_entry, presence: true, if: :required_entry?

     def required_entry?
       ModelC.find(:id).required
     end
   end
   ```

Should I do this

1. in the `:reject_if` option of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` (in modelA class) and in `validates_presence_of modelB_entry` method (in modelB class) OR
2. everything in `:reject_if` OR
3. everything in `:validates_presence_of` ?

Which gets executed first :reject_if or vaildation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reject_if` and `validations` have different purpose.

suppose you have a nested model `modelB` with two fields `name` and `title`, with `name` as mandatory field.

Use of `reject_if`

In the controller `#new` action, you decide to build the first nested object yourself to give user a better UI experience so that he can easily see what else he can add to the form. or the user himself clicks on the "+ Add more" button. But then decides to leave `modelB` blank and not entering any info in it. Now, if you don't use `reject_if` but you have validations the user will get the error message saying field is blank, and he won't be able to submit the form, unless he clicks on `remove` button.

So, in this case you will check if all fields are blank in the `reject_if`, if that is the case we can ignore the record, else let the model do it's work.

Also, keep in mind that reject_if does not guarantees data integrity. As any typical RoR app has multiple entry points.

In my opinion, you should go with the first option. Use both `reject_if` and validations